# How to send SMS without FRM/MSG

Tags: python, smtp

A few days ago I decided to begin working on a program that would be able to send SMS messages without the use of Twilio. For those of you who don't know, Twilio is a website that can be used to send SMS messages with python. However, it holds back many features behind a paywall and is all around sub-par to a program that can send SMS without it. This is what I have so far:

```
import smtplib
from signin import emailadress, password, number
smtplibserver='smtp.gmail.com'

if __name__=="__main__":
  server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtplibserver, 465)
  server.ehlo()
  server.login(emailadress, password)
  print("You're logged in!")

usertext = input("\nWhat is your message? ")
server.sendmail(emailadress, number, usertext)
print("\nSent!\n")
```

(signin is a separate file containing my email address, password, and phone number.)

This method works, but it adds a FRM/MSG to my text. For example, if my message is "Hello, world!" then the text will send as:

FRM:johnappleseed@gmail.com 
MSG:Hello, world!

Twilio sends the message alone. How do I get rid of the FRM/MSG? I know I might have to use a completely different method do to so.

Comment: How does this send an SMS at all, and not an email?

Comment: @mkrieger1 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway